# How to extract error message from failed require in Contract call?

Tags: solidity

I have a function test in contract Test which calls a function in contract A that is expected to fail. How can I extract the information from returnData so that I can include this information in the require statement?

```
contract A {
    event E(string msg);

    function e() public {
        require(false, "BUM!");
        emit E("hello");
    }
}

contract Test {
    A a = new A();

    event E(bytes data);

    function test() public {
        (bool res, bytes memory returnData) = address(a).call(abi.encode(A.e.selector));
        emit E(returnData);
        //require(res, "forward failed: "+..error message from the returnData...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity require() statement does not return an error message per se, since it aborts the operation you will need to implement a [try/catch block](https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/01/29/solidity-0.6-try-catch/)"

```
contract A {
event E(string msg);

function e() public {
    require(false, "BUM!");
    emit E("hello");
}
}

contract Test {
  A a = new A();

  event E(bytes data);

  function test() public {
    (bool res, bytes memory returnData) = address(a).call(abi.encode(A.e.selector));
    try A.e.selector
    {
        //What it does if no error happens...
    }
    catch (bytes memory reason) {
        emit E(reason);
    }
  }
}
```